# CSS: how to make nth table column border thicker when column count is variable?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to make the circled border thicker, but the number of columns can range from 3 to 6, and I can use only plain CSS (no Javascript, SASS or running the CSS through PHP first). The HTML is PHP-generated, but changing the PHP code to generate a class or inline styling is a last resort.

I tried using `colgroup` and `col`, but although `col:first-child {border-right: 2px solid}` worked, `col:last-child {border-left: 2px solid}` put a thicker border on every column under "Percentages."

Is there a way of making that border thicker under the above constraints?

**At the request of dippas**, here is the HTML code in question.

```
<table class="type1">
  <colgroup>
    <!-- note that "4" could range from 3 to 6 -->
    <col span="1">
    <col span="4">
    <col span="4">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">S = small M = medium L = large</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="4">Responses</th>
      <th scope="col" colspan="4">Percentage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">M</th>
      <th scope="col">L</th>
      <th scope="col">Tot</th>
      <th scope="col">S</th>
      <th scope="col">M</th>
      <th scope="col">L</th>
      <th scope="col">Tot</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- following tr structure repeats for each question -->
    <!-- other questions have been removed for brevity -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1. What size Coke do you prefer?</th>
      <td>24</td>
      <td><strong>28</strong></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td><strong>54</strong></td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Again, note that the number of columns is variable. In this case, the possible answers to the question were "Small, Medium, or Large," but they could be "On a scale of 1 to 5, etc., etc."

Comment: can you show the output code? i might have a possible solution..if it is what i am thinking

Comment: @dippas Thank you. I have added to HTML code to the question.

Comment: Sorry the HTML isnt generated the way i was thinking!, you should then add a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution, which uses a pseudo-element to create a border that spans the height of the table:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}

thead > tr:first-of-type th:not(:first-of-type)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: calc(100% - 3px);
}
```

This assumes the colspans are on the first row of the table in the `thead` section – as is the case in your example.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzm1eq9a/)

Comment: Wow! I'll have to digest that slowly. It works in IE9 and the latest Chrome, so that's good enough for me. It seems you're drawing an empty box and using it to simulate a border. I didn't even know that was possible. On my system, the pseudo-border is ever a bit far to the right, but that must be a consequence of my existing CSS. [link](http://clicketyhome.com/form.gif). I'll go over it but your Fiddle certainly proves it works. This may be what V-tech meant by the last resort being a better option, but you have certainly answered what I asked. Thank you for going the extra mile!

Comment: Ignore the part about "a bit far to the right." I now see the negative margin in the Fiddle.

Comment: You got it.  I usually add padding to table cells, so the negative margin compensates for that.  Interesting challenge but worth it, because I'll be using this for my own tables in the future.